# Modifying landscape and portrait images to thumb in php

Tags: php, image

I have images with landscape and portrait view , i need to convert them as thumb images with same proportionality what they had  , Could anyone guide me how to solve this .

Thanks .

Comment: Hey, add what you have tried, and where you are stuck, with the minimal amount of code.. before you get downvoted of the site.

Comment: I would recommend this tutorial, it's the way I do it. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362
There is also one here specifically for thumbnails. http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-thumbnails--net-1818